# How to add Localization menu in Opencart

Tags: php, opencart

I am using a 1.5.3.1 version of Opencart. I am getting a problem in editing the GeoZone for a store. In the admin panel there is no Localization menu. As a result, I am not been able to  customize GeoZone.

How to add the Localization menu on menubar, so that I can configure my GeoZones?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure but it is help full to you read it.

**Localizing OpenCart for Language, Currency**

see this url:-

http://ecommercedeveloper.com/articles/3107-localizing-opencart-for-language-currency/

OpenCart 1.5 comes with the capability to support multiple languages, currencies and other localization features. However, the standard installation only includes one language: English. Furthermore, the British heritage of OpenCart’s developer, Daniel Kerr, is prevalent throughout. For example, one menu in the backend is labeled “localisation,” instead of the American-ized spelling of “localization.” Online inquiries use the word “enquiry.” Dates, by default, are displayed in day/month/year format, whereas Americans are more accustomed to a month/day/year format.

**OR**

**OpenCart. How to add a new language**

see below url:-

http://www.templatemonster.com/help/opencart-how-to-add-a-new-language.html

Answer (score 0):

if you installed opencart successfully, you suppose see the Localization menu under System. I use the most updated version 1.5.4.1. Maybe you can try the new version or try to uninstall yours, then install again.